# Define a new "Ctrl-a <key>" shortcut in GNU screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (or whatever my command sequence is) followed by a lowercase <kbd>k</kbd> rather than the uppercase one that screen defaults to. I've played around with the `bindkey` directive a bit but the specified key combinations don't require first entering the command sequence (e.g., Ctrl-a).

What's the best way to achieve this while allowing for changes to the command sequence (I don't want to hardcode in "Ctrl-a" somewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape key is implicit in the bind command.

for example :

```
bind 'j' kill
```

will bind the kill window action to your <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>

also, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,  <kbd>K</kbd> already do the same thing in screen

more on binkey [here](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_13.html)

Comment: For my screen installation, only capital K worked but `bind "k" kill` did the trick. Thanks!